# Calculating percentage by group using Teradata

Tags: sql, sas, teradata

I'm trying to create a table that displays the percentage of counts per state dependent on the indicator.

Here's an example of the dataset I'm using to create my new table.

```
+-------------+-------+-------+
|  Indicator  | State | Count | 
+-------------+-------+-------+
| Registered  | CA    |    25 |
| Registered  | FL    |    12 |
| Total       | CA    |    50 |
| Total       | FL    |    36 |
+-------------+-------+-------+
```

I'm trying to create a new table that would have a Percentage for each corresponding row like this:

```
+-------------+-------+-------+------------+
|  Indicator  | State | Count | Percentage |
+-------------+-------+-------+------------+
| Registered  | CA    |    25 |         50 |
| Registered  | FL    |    12 |       33.3 |
| Total       | CA    |    50 |          . |
| Total       | FL    |    36 |          . |
+-------------+-------+-------+------------+
```

So far, i've tried doing the below query:

```
select indicator, state, count
, case when (select count from table where indicator='Registered') * 100 / (select count from table where indicator='Total')
when indicator = 'Total' then . end as Percentage

from table;
```

This doesn't work because I get an error: "Subquery evaluated more than one row." I'm guessing its because I'm not taking into account the state in the case when statement, but i'm not sure as to how I would go about that.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Aren't you just doing a join between the set of records with Indicator='Total' and the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join the table back with itself.

```
select a.indicator, a.state, a.count
     , case when (indicator='Total') then null
            else 100 * a.count/b.count 
       end as Percentage
from table a
inner join (select state,count from table where indicator='Total') b 
  on a.state = b.state
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when indicator <> 'Total'
             then count * 100.0 / sum(case when indicator = 'Total' then indicator end) over (partition by state)
        end) as percentage
from t;
```

Comment: Not sure if I follow. I don't see a window function in the code you posted. I'm also wondering how I'm going to use a sum function in the way you posted since it'll require a numeric argument.

Comment: @dw0000 . . . It is there now.